# Connecting Android Phone to local host

Tags: android, android-networking, androidhttpclient

In my application i am using API's which are hosted on local server, and can be accessed on network. On emulator it works fine as it is connected to proper network. When I am using app on my phone it wont.

Is it possible to access local API's through phone with our normal internet connection?

I am using below http code for accessing API's.

```
 public String getResponse(String url, int method, String postParameter) {
    HttpResponse response = null;
    // Creating HTTP client
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Creating HTTP Post
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    // Building post parameters
    // key and value pair
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jObj", postParameter));

    // Url Encoding the POST parameters
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // writing error to Log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Making HTTP Request
    try {
         response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        // writing response to log
        Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```

Is there any setting which we can do for accessing through our normal internet?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Instead of using localhost, use IP address of system in url, e.g., use http://192.168.1.1:8080/example instead of http://localhost:8080/example. (192.168.1.1 is just a demo ip address)

Comment: Yes I am using in that way only. eg - http://10.74.161.243:8080/xyz.. Its not on my machine, API's are hosted on some other. How can I access these api's through my phone internet like Vodafone internet

Comment: Are both devices connected to the same network? I mean are you connecting both the computer and device to the same router?

Answer (score 1):

If you have it hosted on your local machine, you will have to find a way to connect both your phone and your local machine on the same network (most commonly Wifi). A simple work-around to this is creating a hotspot  in your android device and connecting your local machine to it. Make sure to set the correct IP address in the android app.

Answer (score 0):

Find your local machine ip address where the api's are hosted
using ipconfig and pass on the ip address in url 
your url should be like 192.168.0.102 which is assigned by modem.

Comment: Yes I am using in that way only. eg - 10.74.161.243:8080/xyz.. Its not on my machine, API's are hosted on some other. How can I access these api's through my phone internet like Vodafone internet

Comment: Yes you can also connect to the local server also at the same time when you are connected to mobile data. Turn on your hotspot and connect local server with your mobile wifi hotspot. and then try using the apis with both localhost and local ip.

Answer (score 0):

Answering as I cant comment, Please check that your phone is connected to your network and not using mobile data or some other WIFI network outside of your network.

Comment: No its connected to my data. Thats what I asked that if its connected to my vodafone internet is it possible to connect to local server. I think its not but asking to be confirmed